# Is it possible to have master detail option sets in DHIS2?

Tags: dhis2

In DHIS2, is it possible to have master detail option sets? for example countries as an master option set and cities as detail option set.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible at the moment. Something similar is asked see [this jira issue](https://jira.dhis2.org/browse/DHIS2-975). Master is basically the group, while detail its members.